# Jquery 1.9 - declare variable after load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

```
<div class="main_content grid_9 clearfix omega">
    <div class="basic_info">
        <p>You have
        <?php
            $msg =  count($messages);
            $msg_tekst = ($msg  == 1) ? 'message.' : 'messages.';
        echo $msg . ' ' . $msg_tekst;
         ?>
        </p>
        <p>Show all
            <a role=show_msg  href="<?php echo base_url('admin/contact_messages/unread') ?>">unread </a>
            |
            <a role=show_msg  href="<?php echo base_url('admin/contact_messages/read') ?>">read </a>
            messages.
        </p>
    </div>

    <!-- START CONTACT MESSAGES -->
    <div class="contact_messages">
        <?php foreach ($messages as $msg) : ?>
            <article class="box contact_message clearfix">
                <h2><?php echo $msg['name'] ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $msg['comment'] ?></p>
                <a role=delete href="<?php echo base_url('admin/contact_messages_delete/' .  $msg['id_contact']) ?>">Delete Message</a>

                <?php if($msg['read'] == 0) : ?>
                    <a role=read href="<?php echo base_url('admin/contact_messages_read/' .  $msg['id_contact'] . '/read') ?>">Mark as read</a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a role=unread href="<?php echo base_url('admin/contact_messages_read/' .  $msg['id_contact']) ?>">Mark as unread</a>
                <?php endif ?>
            </article>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- END CONTACT MESSAGES -->

</div>
<!-- END MAIN_CONTENT -->

<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

    var basic_info = $('.basic_info'),
    show_msg = basic_info.find('a[role=show_msg]'),
    contact_messages = $('.contact_messages'),
    read = contact_messages.find('a[role=read], a[role=unread]'),
    title = 'Contact Message Delete',
    message = 'Are you sure you want to delete this message?';
    delete_admin(title, message);

    function msg_load(container, url)
    {
        container.slideUp('fast', function(){
                container.empty().load(url, function(){
                    container.slideDown('fast');
            });
        });
    };

    // AJAX MESSAGES SHOWING
    show_msg.on('click', function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
        url = $this.attr('href'),
        url_info =  url + ' .basic_info > *',
        url_msg =  url + ' .contact_messages > *';

        msg_load(basic_info, url_info);
        msg_load(contact_messages, url_msg);

        return false;
    });

 });
</script>
```

After load, variables that are set are not usable (or they don't exists). How can redeclare this variables (HTML part for the variables is inside container)?

[Page Render](http://pastebin.ca/2366350)

Comment: Post the entire example not peicemeal. Edit- The entire script I mean.

Comment: The PHP isn't the problem, post your entire script. Or at least a smallest reproducible version of it.

Comment: This is complete code (I have copied hole page).

Comment: Then why is "Variables settings" and "Load function" in seperate code areas? I want to see exactly how the file is laid out. Basically @DavidHedlund below is probably correct, its a DOM load problem, but without seeing the actual file I can't tell you the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed that code was divided. This is the hole file.

Comment: I don't see a `delete_admin` function defined. Are you sure you don't just have a syntax error on the page?

Comment: **delete_admin** function is created in a separate file and it is working, there is no syntax error (it is not important for my problem)/

Comment: Can you please post a rendered version of the html (IE after the page loads to the client) ?

Comment: I have linked render page to pastebin (It is a bit large, and I guess it is not practically to paste it in raw form)

Comment: That's fine. Does this reproduce the issue your seeing? http://jsfiddle.net/LGDex/ Edit- This one is trimmed down even more:  http://jsfiddle.net/LGDex/1/

Comment: Yes, this is the problem I am facing. After **load** JS part of the code is not working (links can be clicked, but they are not working via JS).

Comment: Do these requests return anything ? `http://10.0.0.101/pmb/admin/contact_messages/unread .basic_info > *`
 `http://10.0.0.101/pmb/admin/contact_messages/unread .contact_messages > *` ?  The only thing I can see is that your not using the return value of `load` to fill in the given content div. Those url's also look a little odd, with what appears to be selectors in the request...

Comment: Using selectors in url I can load part of the page I want. **load** is working - after the call, containers are populated, but variables are not working. As far as I can tell, I need to create them again in order to use JS functions normally.

Comment: After the slideDown call? There is no code there... ?

Comment: I first empty the container and then I load data via load function. Because I did slideUp before that I need do do slideDown in order to show container.

Answer (score 0):

for `basic_info` to be a reference to all elements of the `basic_info` class, the assignment has to be made after DOMReady. If the number of `basic_info` elements may change, the assignment has to be made at the point in time for which you want the information to be valid.

Comment: **basic_info** elements varies, based on query which is called in load function. Where in load function I need to create variables again.